# Jenkins Multibranch pipeline: How to select a build node?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Jenkins multibranch pipeline always performs checkout on master node. In my case I want to make my build on another node. My script in Jenkinsfile looks like this:

```
node('osx') {
    ...
}
```

I'm forced to checkout `env.BRANCH` on my node myself again to perform a build. It will be much better to perform pipeline build on selected node from the beginning, but I can not find how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have `checkout scm` in your Jenkinsfile on the branch?

Like so:

```
node('osx') {
    checkout scm
    ...
}
```